# How to pass variable name inside for-each loop in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, exslt

I'm new to Xslt I'm reading xml data using xslt. for example

```
<head>
    <root>
        <data>
            <Name>xxx</Name>      
            <age>10</age>
        </data>
        <data>
            <Name>yyy</Name>      
            <age>20</age>
        </data>
        <data>
            <Name>zzz</Name>      
            <age>15</age>
        </data>
    </root>
</head>
```

When I tried use below xslt

```
<xsl:template match="head">
  <xsl:element name="Root1">
      <xsl:for-each select="//head/root/data">
         <xsl:element name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="$select_Name"/>
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:element name="age">
            <xsl:value-of select="$select_age"/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

My c# code is

```
  XslTransform xsl=new XslTransform();
  xsl.Load("xsltfile");
  xsl.Transform("inputxml.xml","outputxml.xml");
```

I'm not getting proper output when i use the above xslt file. whereas when I give the xpath of the element to a variable in another xslt file and include the xslt into this xslt and pass variable name instead of hardcoded value `<xsl:value-of select="$select_Name"/>` like this whereas $name is declared as `<xsl:variable name="select_Name" select="//head/root/data/Name"/>` im getting the value of name for the field of Age. Anyone faced this kind of issue? or can you share how to pass the variable name instead of element name for the value inside for-each loop?

Comment: Post the code with the problem please. It is kind of hard to follow and understand you question without it.

Comment: 1. You don't show where these variables are defined. 2. I don't see **why** you need these variables; you can - and should - use simply  `<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>`. -- Keep in mind that a variable can hold either a reference to a node-set or a value - not a path that will be evaluated later.